# MongoDB convert BsonTimestamp to Date

Tags: mongodb

Is there an (efficient) way of converting a MongoDB document field of type `BsonTimestamp` to a `Date` field. Do I have to create a temporary field to store the Date? Do I have to write a custom JS migration script and loop over every item for this?

from this:

```
  "ts": {
    "$timestamp": {
      "t": 1620986905,
      "i": 1
    }
  }
```

to this:

```
  "ts": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1620986905626"
    }
  }
```

Comment: You can try `ts: {
        $toDate: {
          $multiply: ["$ts.t", 1000]
        }
      }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in the [official doc](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/bson-types/#document-bson-type-date),

> The BSON timestamp type is for internal MongoDB use. For most cases, in application development, you will want to use the BSON date type. See
> [Date](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/bson-types/#std-label-document-bson-type-date) for more information.

For your case, you are suggested to use a plain bson date field. You can convert your existing data with `$toDate`

```js
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      ts: {
        $toDate: "$ts"
      }
    }
  }
],
{
  multi: true
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4vgEAA9Ffli)